# My mini game-project runs only when the window is closed

Tags: python, pygame

I write a mini game in python for a college project. It is at an early stage but i have a problem on running. When i run the .py file, a black window appears. When i press the "X" button to close the window, ONLY THEN my background shows up for a sec and then the window close. In a few words my game runs only when i close the window.

```
import pygame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (50, 50, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
player_speed = 10


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        #self.walls = None

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def move(self, walls):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom


class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.set_alpha(0)
        self.image.fill([255, 255, 255])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x


class Level(object):
    wall_list = None
    enemy_sprites = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()


class Level1(Level):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        walls = [........]                 
        for item in walls:
            wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3])
            self.wall_list.add(wall)


class Level2(Level):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        walls = [.....]
        for item in walls:
            wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3])
            self.wall_list.add(wall)


def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 800])
    pygame.display.set_caption('GAME')
    player = Player(100, 100)
    movingsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    movingsprites.add(player)

    levels = []
    level = Level1()
    levels.append(level)
    level = Level2()
    levels.append(level)
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = levels[current_level_no]

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.changespeed(-player_speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.changespeed(player_speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.changespeed(0, -player_speed)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.changespeed(0, player_speed)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.changespeed(player_speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.changespeed(-player_speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.changespeed(0, player_speed)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.changespeed(0, -player_speed)

        player.move(current_level.wall_list)

    if player.rect.x > 900 and player.rect.y < 100:
        if current_level_no == 0:
            current_level_no = 1
            current_level = levels[current_level_no]
            player.rect.x = 50
            player.rect.y = 450
        elif current_level_no == 1:
            current_level_no = 2
            current_level = levels[current_level_no]
            player.rect.x = 790
        else:
            current_level_no = 0
            current_level = levels[current_level_no]
            player.rect.x = 790

    '''if player.rect.x > 1000:
        if current_level_no == 0:
            current_level_no = 1
            current_level = levels[current_level_no]
            player.rect.x = 0
        elif current_level_no == 1:
            current_level_no = 2
            current_level = levels[current_level_no]
            player.rect.x = 0
        else:
            current_level_no = 0
            current_level = levels[current_level_no]
            player.rect.x = 0'''

    if current_level_no == 0:
        background_image1 = pygame.image.load("level1background.jpg").convert()
        screen.blit(background_image1, [0, 0])
    else:
        background_image2 = pygame.image.load("level2background.jpg").convert()
        screen.blit(background_image2, [0, 0])

    movingsprites.draw(screen)
    current_level.wall_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It's not reasonable to ask us to read through all your code -- a question should have a [mcve], the *shortest possible* code that shows the same problem. (If you can take an element out of your game and still have the same problem, you *should* do that, before asking a question here; this process is also described in the "tricks for trimming" section of http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Global call to ```pygame.quit()``` looks very suspicious. But yes, shortest possible code if you want real help.

Comment: That said, a good place to start here is adding some debug logging. Is your event loop being entered before you hit the close window? Which events *are* seen prior to that point? Instrument your code, and that'll make it a lot easier to figure out exactly which parts are and aren't reached before and after the close event.

Comment: I believe the indentation of your `main()` function is wrong - I'd expect `pygame.display.flip()` and the surrounding code to be in the while loop?

Comment: Due to indentation errors, the last statement in your `while not done` loop is `player.move(current_level.wall_list)`. So the rest of the code that handles drawing sprites and updating the display only runs once, after a `pygame.QUIT` event. That seems to match the symptoms you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I’m sorry about the big unneeded code, but I really doesn’t know what was wrong.

I make my code, my “while” instead BUT: after I put commands in the while loop and make the code runs correctly, the “player” move very slowly and “dot to dot”. Before the “player” move was very normal and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `walls = [....]` syntax errors, basically the problem is the main loop.

The big issue is that the tail-end of the `while not done` loop did not include the last two code blocks because of an indentation error.  All the code after the line `if player.rect.x > 900 and player.rect.y < 100:` was not part of the loop because it was indented 1-level to the left.  Correcting this basically fixed everything.

```
def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 800])
    pygame.display.set_caption('GAME')
    player = Player(100, 100)
    movingsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    movingsprites.add(player)

    levels = []
    level = Level1()
    levels.append(level)
    level = Level2()
    levels.append(level)
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = levels[current_level_no]
    background_image1 = pygame.image.load("level1background.jpg").convert()
    background_image2 = pygame.image.load("level2background.jpg").convert()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.changespeed(-player_speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.changespeed(player_speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.changespeed(0, -player_speed)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.changespeed(0, player_speed)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.changespeed(player_speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.changespeed(-player_speed, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.changespeed(0, player_speed)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    player.changespeed(0, -player_speed)

        player.move(current_level.wall_list)

        if player.rect.x > 900 and player.rect.y < 100:
            if current_level_no == 0:
                current_level_no = 1
                current_level = levels[current_level_no]
                player.rect.x = 50
                player.rect.y = 450
            elif current_level_no == 1:
                current_level_no = 2
                current_level = levels[current_level_no]
                player.rect.x = 790
            else:
                current_level_no = 0
                current_level = levels[current_level_no]
                player.rect.x = 790

        if current_level_no == 0:
            screen.blit(background_image1, [0, 0])
        else:
            screen.blit(background_image2, [0, 0])

        movingsprites.draw(screen)
        current_level.wall_list.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Also I moved the `pygame.quit()` line to the end of the program.